# How to scan all XNB files in Content Manager?

Tags: c#, xna, game-engine, monogame

So I'm building a game with MonoGame in VS. I'm using the Content Pipeline from MonoGame (that generates XNB files).

The thing is that my game is expansible (it is a rhytim game that user can download songs/charts). So I had to support "plug-in" XNB files.

So I already made my Custom Importer / Reader / Writer for my custom types, but I cannot find a way to scan the content folder to find which xnb's are available. For example if the user adds a Song1.xnb at Content folder, how will I know (programatically) that the file is there?

I couldn't find any showFiles or scanContent in ContentManager to list all available files. How can I find which files are in my content folder in a Cross-Platform way?

Example of my structure:

```
Content
  - Songs
    - Song0
      - 0.xnb
      - 1.xnb
      - Song0.xnb
    - Song1
      - 0.xnb
      - Song0.xnb
```

So my song folder always have a **{Folder}.xnb** file that have the structure for the songs (and also a reference for X.xnb (0,1,2 ...)). But I cannot find what folders does exists on the **Songs** folder so I can call `Load<Music>("Songs\\{SongFolder}\\{SongFolder}.xnb")`

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this function to load all textures in my folder.

```
public static           List<Texture2D>     Textures(string folderPath)
{
    if (!folderPath.StartsWith(@"\")) folderPath = @"\" + folderPath;
    List<string> paths = Directory.GetFiles(Help.RootDir(Content.RootDirectory) + folderPath).ToList();
    List<Texture2D> images = new List<Texture2D>();
    foreach (string s in paths)
    {
        if (s.EndsWith(".xnb"))
            images.Add(Texture(s.Replace(Content.RootDirectory, "").Replace(".xnb", "")));
    }
    return images;
}
```

The `folderPath` variable should be path from content's folder (without it) to te folder you want to load all textures/songs from. In your case, pass "Songs\Songs0" as a parameter, replace *Texture2D* to *Song* or *SoundEffect*, and it will work fine.

Also, the `Help.RootDir` is a simple function I made:

```
public static string RootDir(string s)
{ return s.Substring(0, s.LastIndexOf(@"\")); }
```

And also include `System.IO;`

Comment: Weird, it does not seens to work here. I get an exception on RootDir function because there is no \ in my Content.RootDirectory (it is just "Content") - Also Directory.GetFiles(Content.RootDirectory) does not return anything.

Comment: Ok so my mistake. I didn't saw that GetFiles only return files (and I dont have files in the folder I was looking for). With GetDirectories it worked. Thanks!